# Splitting the value of an input and making the results url-friendly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this form where a user can input tags (tag_list input) like "Graphic design, illustration etc." I then want to transform these tags in to url friendlt strings, like "graphic-design" before i save them to the database so that i can use them in my html as classes. I've gotten it to work where the user only enters one tag into the field, like "Graphic design", but if the user enters 2 or more fields my code won't work and i have no idea how to get it to work.

Any ideas?

The model code:

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :url_friendly_tags

  def url_friendly_tags
    self.tag_slug = self.tag_list.to_s.gsub(/\s+/, '_').gsub(/[^\w\-]/, '')
  end

end
```

The view:

```
<% semantic_form_for @work do |f| %>
    <% f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.tag_list %>
        <%= f.input :tag_slug, :as => :hidden %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process a list of tags separated by comma (or semicolon), perhaps you need to `self.tag_list.split(/\s*[;,]\s*/).collect {|s| s.gsub(/\s+/, '_').gsub(/[^\w\-]/, '')}.join(",")` or similar (i.e. split the user input before processing)? This should do the trick, provided that `self.tag_list` is a string.

*Previous answer, for the sake of conversation*

I misunderstood the problem, so I suggested to use [route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing):

```
match 'books/*section/:title' => 'books#show'
```

For a url `books/foo/bar/baz` this route will populate `params[:section]` with a string `foo/bar`, so you need to `split` it on `/`.

Comment: Updated my description of the problem.